# Indicator functions with conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, machine-learning

This feels like a silly question. I'm reading somewhere that

$$ \mathbb{P} (Y = 1,h(x)=-1\mid X=x) = \mathbb{P}(Y=1\mid X=x) \mathbb{ I }_{\{h(x) = -1\}} $$

where $\mathbb{ I }$ is the indicator function (not sure the best way to LaTeX this).
Here $h$ is a deterministic classifier.
I'm wondering why we can just 'do' this, it doesn't feel like this aligns with my common sense of manipulating probability equations. ie. Can we treat the events $Y=1$ and $h(x) = -1$ conditionally independent given $X=x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This come frome the fact that if $X$ is $\mathcal G-$measurable, then $$\mathbb E[XY\mid \mathcal G]=X\mathbb E[Y\mid \mathcal G].$$

Since you have that $\boldsymbol 1_{\{h(X)=-1\}}$ is $\sigma (X)-$measurable, you have that \begin{align*}
\mathbb P\{Y=1, h(X)=-1\mid X\}&:=\mathbb E[\boldsymbol 1_{\{Y=1\}}\boldsymbol 1_{\{h(X)=-1\}}\mid X]\\&=\boldsymbol 1_{\{h(X)=-1\}}\mathbb E[\boldsymbol 1_{\{Y=1\}}\mid X]\\
&=\boldsymbol 1_{\{h(X)=-1\}}\mathbb P\{Y=1\mid X\}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Ouch. I'm a bit lost on the measurability step. Is that really the only way to show it?

Comment: Is there a problem with simply saying for all $x$, LHS = RHS, so we have equality?

Comment: I'm sorry, but there are no easier way to prove this equality. @ChristopherTurnbull